# #define from main (.ino) not considered by comiler in own libaries

Tags: library, c-preprocessor

I have got the problem, that my #define from main (.ino) is not considered by the comiler in my own libaries. This #define MQTT_MODULE is only considered in the main (.ino) programm, but not in MyRemoteLib.cpp
This example works normally, if I compile it with gcc.

Code in my Test.ino :

```
#define         MQTT_MODULE             1
#include        "MyRemoteLib.h"
loop() {
  my_test() ;
}
```

Code in MyRemoteLib.h

```
#define     MYREMOTELIB_H
#define     MY_TEST         1
#if         MQTT_MODULE
  #define       MQTT_MOD_R              1
#endif
```

Code in MyRemoteLib.cpp :

```
#include        "MyRemoteLib.h"
void my_test() {
  #if   MQTT_MOD_R
      test.... > nothing -> ignored by compiler
  #endif
  #if   MQTT_MODULE
      test.... > nothing -> ignored by compiler
  #endif
  #if   MYTEST
      test.... > error-> not ignored by compiler
  #endif
}
```

Comment: Your approach of using #define to selectively include different parts of your library is doomed to fail, because it does not work that way. You might want to learn more how to build a "real" library. In a tiny nutshell, separate all parts in their own source. When the linker resolves references, it will only add the needed modules. However, if this is doable with the Arduino IDE, is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. The library and the main program are two
different compilation units: there are processed by the compiler
separately.

In the main program, the inclusion of the header file yields this:

```cpp
#define         MQTT_MODULE             1
// Included from MyRemoteLib.h:
#define     MYREMOTELIB_H
#define     MY_TEST         1
#if         MQTT_MODULE
  #define       MQTT_MOD_R              1
#endif
// end of included code
loop() {
  my_test() ;
}
```

The remaining preprocessor code has no effect at all.

In the library, the same inclusion yields this:

```cpp
// Included from MyRemoteLib.h:
#define     MYREMOTELIB_H
#define     MY_TEST         1
#if         MQTT_MODULE
  #define       MQTT_MOD_R              1
#endif
// end of included code
void my_test() {
  #if   MQTT_MOD_R
      test.... > nothing -> ignored by compiler
  #endif
  #if   MQTT_MODULE
      test.... > nothing -> ignored by compiler
  #endif
  #if   MYTEST
      test.... > error-> not ignored by compiler
  #endif
}
```

The conditional compilation gives an empty `my_test()` (that is, unless
by `MYTEST` you actually mean `MY_TEST`).

I do not know what you are trying to achieve, but you may look at ways
to put the code to be conditionally compiled in the header itself. You
may try using inline functions, or maybe templates.

**Edit**: about removing code using conditional compilation: this is not
always as useful as it may sound, for two reasons.

1. By default, the Arduino IDE compiles your code with the options
   `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`, and links it with
   `-Wl,--gc-sections`. This means that any function or method that is
   never used, or any global variable that is never referenced, is not
   included in the final executable.
2. The code is also compiled with `-flto`, which enables [link-time
   (full program) optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization). This means that code that depends
   on a condition that is always false (the conditional expression can
   be resolved as a compile-time constant) is also removed from the
   final executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well I try to achieve a universal code in my own library's so I can "activate" a "Module" in my main program. And I thought the pre-processer is the best ways, so it even won't be complied (if I don't need it). For example, some sensor functions should only send mqtt msg if I activate my "wifi module"... otherwise the compiler also complains!
That's why I prefer to use #defines. Also if I use the "normal" gcc compiler it works.

Comment: @stevo Some of this is probably intended as a comment on Edgar Bonet's answer and some of it *may* be something that's supposed to be edited into the question. Careful that you don't edit the question out from underneath the existing answer. This is not a forum. The way it's supposed to work is that there are questions with matching answers. Not a forum thread.

Comment: @stevo I doubt that your "normal" gcc works differently and "sees" the #define in the source of another translation unit. BTW, the compiler used by the Arduino IDE is a gcc, too.